# Unable to open shared SQLite database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sqlite, linqpad

> Unable to open database file

That's the error I get when trying to open a SQLite db file that is shared, I've already allowed read/write to everyone when I shared the folder containing the db file.

I'm accessing the file using LINQPad or [SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) both gives me the same error.

However I can successfully work with the database using my Windows Form application with the following declaration for the connection

```
Dim litecon As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\10.10.10.10\SQLite\SQLiteDB.db;Version=3;Password=1;", True)
```

I set `parseViaFramework` to `True`

Comment: Try Firefox Sqlite Manager plugin

Comment: Try create a Network mapping and open it through the network mapping. Sometimes some software don't like URLs starting with \\10.100.... patterns